# How to filter dates of time window relative to column value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a Pandas data frame `df` with columns of `ID`, `DATE` (continuous year-month dates of the same six-month-long period) and `FIX_DATE` (constant year-month date per `ID` always falling in the second half of the given `DATE` period). Multiple `ID`s are with over the same `DATE` periods. Example:

```
ID DATE    FIX_DATE

01 2023-01 2023-05
01 2023-02 2023-05
01 2023-03 2023-05
01 2023-04 2023-05
01 2023-05 2023-05
01 2023-06 2023-05
02 2023-01 2023-04
02 2023-02 2023-04
02 2023-03 2023-04
02 2023-04 2023-04
02 2023-05 2023-04
02 2023-06 2023-04
```

I need a query what results filtered rows of the respective `ID`s where the rows are three-month-long records of each `ID` closing with the `FIX_DATE` date per users. So in case of my example, the result is:

```
ID DATE    FIX_DATE

01 2023-03 2023-05
01 2023-04 2023-05
01 2023-05 2023-05
02 2023-02 2023-04
02 2023-03 2023-04
02 2023-04 2023-04
```

How could get the desired output in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Count difference in months by periods in [`Serie.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and get values by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
diff = (pd.to_datetime(df['FIX_DATE']).dt.to_period('m')
            .sub(pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('m')))

out = df[diff.apply(lambda x: x.n).between(0,2)]
print (out)
   ID     DATE FIX_DATE
2   1  2023-03  2023-05
3   1  2023-04  2023-05
4   1  2023-05  2023-05
7   2  2023-02  2023-04
8   2  2023-03  2023-04
9   2  2023-04  2023-04
```

Or another idea is filter first by difference of columns and use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
out = df[df['DATE'].le(df['FIX_DATE'])].groupby('ID').tail(3)
print (out)

   ID     DATE FIX_DATE
2   1  2023-03  2023-05
3   1  2023-04  2023-05
4   1  2023-05  2023-05
7   2  2023-02  2023-04
8   2  2023-03  2023-04
9   2  2023-04  2023-04
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the number of periods (convert using [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)) between the two dates and keep those within your limit using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3

d = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y-%m').dt.to_period('M')
f = pd.to_datetime(df['FIX_DATE'], format='%Y-%m').dt.to_period('M')

out = df[(f-d).map(lambda d: d.n).between(0, N-1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID     DATE FIX_DATE
2   1  2023-03  2023-05
3   1  2023-04  2023-05
4   1  2023-05  2023-05
7   2  2023-02  2023-04
8   2  2023-03  2023-04
9   2  2023-04  2023-04
```

Intermediates:

```
    ID     DATE FIX_DATE        d        f  n  0:(N-1)
0    1  2023-01  2023-05  2023-01  2023-05  4    False
1    1  2023-02  2023-05  2023-02  2023-05  3    False
2    1  2023-03  2023-05  2023-03  2023-05  2     True
3    1  2023-04  2023-05  2023-04  2023-05  1     True
4    1  2023-05  2023-05  2023-05  2023-05  0     True
5    1  2023-06  2023-05  2023-06  2023-05 -1    False
6    2  2023-01  2023-04  2023-01  2023-04  3    False
7    2  2023-02  2023-04  2023-02  2023-04  2     True
8    2  2023-03  2023-04  2023-03  2023-04  1     True
9    2  2023-04  2023-04  2023-04  2023-04  0     True
10   2  2023-05  2023-04  2023-05  2023-04 -1    False
11   2  2023-06  2023-04  2023-06  2023-04 -2    False
```